# flex grid scrollbar pushing all columns to the left

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex-mx

I have a flex grid where I have the `verticalScrollPolicy="auto"`. But every time when the scrollbar appears all the columns get pushed to the left, making the columns not align as they should. I tried setting minWidth on all the columns to prevent this, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior of flex dataGrids. If it bothers you, you can set verticalScrollPolicy="on" which will draw the scrollbar whether or not it's needed, and the grid will not resize.